# Puting a BoxSizer in the middle of its panel

Tags: user-interface, layout, wxpython, positioning

I've written some code which displays a wx.Frame, within which there is a wx.Panel, within which there is a jpg. The jpg is the same size as the frame, so that when the program starts up the user is presented with a picture covering the whole of the window. Overlayed over the top of this picture, and **in the centre of the panel** I want to put a wx.BoxSizer containing various widgets. So far I've got the sizer visible but, try as I might, I cannot shift it from the uppermost lefthand corner of the panel to the center. No doubt there are many round-about ways of doing this involving grids and borders, but before I set off down this path, I was wondering if I'm missing something simple and there is a command that can be used to position in widget in a specified part of a panel.

ps. I also know I could do this using absolute positioning, but I want to be able to resize the window while keeping the sizer at its centre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you can't see a sizer. But regardless, you don't really center a sizer. You center the widgets INSIDE the sizer. So when you add a widget to the sizer, you'd want to do something like this:

```
mySizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
mySizer.Add(widget, 0, wx.CENTER|wx.ALL, 5)
```

Now, that will only center it horizontally. If you want it in the very center of the panel, then create another BoxSizer that is oriented horizontally and add the first sizer to the second one, centering it too.

```
hSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
hSizer.Add(mySizer, 0, wx.CENTER)
```